# How can I add Redis retries in goworker

Tags: go, redis, pool

I want redis connections to reconnect for the specified number of times before timeout is raised.

I am using "github.com/benmanns/goworker".

But I checked in this library while initialising a pool of connections they are not taking any such parameters as input.